# NuGet spec command ignoring metadata from project properties

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am generating a NuGet package of a library in .NET Standard 2.0 using Visual Studio 2022.

I go to Project properties and edit the project information as shown in the pictures.

[image: Project Properties 1]

[image: Project Properties 2]

[image: Project Properties 3]

When i use the command `NuGet spec`to generate the manifest, the values are not corresponding to the project metadata edited in Visual Studio.

[image: NuSpec file]

I tried several solution found on web but none worked, even unloading the project, reloading and cleaning it. It looks like nuspec is ignoring the properties of the project.

I know I can edit the metadata by hand, but I am wondering why this happens. If I make several rebuild of the package I have to edit manually the entire spec file each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that there is no need to call NuGet spec and follow the manual procedure in order to create a package in Visual Studio 2022.

In Visual Studio 2022, it is enough to right-click the project and select Properties.
Then in the *Package* section, check the box **Produce a package on build**.

A NuGet package of the project, using the metadata provided in the project properties, will be created in the `bin/Debug` or 'bin/Release` folder. The folder depends on your building choices.

[image]